# How to avoid a possible missing cache file in PHP?

Tags: php, caching, if-statement, file-get-contents

I have a simple caching system as

```
if (file_exists($cache)) {
echo file_get_contents($cache);
// if coming here when $cache is deleting, then nothing to display
}
else {
// PHP process
}
```

We regularly delete outdated cache files, e.g. deleting all caches after 1 hour. Although this process is very fast, but I am thinking that a cache file can be deleted right between the `if statement` and `file_get_contents` processes.

I mean when `if statement` checks the existence of cache file, it exists; but when `file_get_contents` tries to catch it, it is no longer there (deleted by simultaneous cache deleting process).

`file_get_contents` locks the file to avoid the undergoing delete process during the read process. But the file can be deleted when the `if statement` sends the PHP process to the first condition (before start of the `file_get_contents`).

Is there any approach to avoid this? Is the cache deleting system different?

**NOTE:** I did not face any practical problem, as it is not very probable to catch this event, but logically it is possible, and should happen on heavy loads.

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php - if your checking process and your deleting process both require an exclusive lock, then they can't both run at the same time.

Comment: @andrewsi `file_get_contents` lock the file for read, but `if statement` does not. The file lock guarantees that the file will not be deleted during read, but is there a guarantee that file will not be deleted after the '`if statement` return `true`?

Comment: Classic race condition.  Google mutual exclusion and semaphores.  Either get lock along the lines andrewsi is suggesting, or be pessimistic and possibly regenerate cache files a little more than really needed.

Comment: @All - get an exclusive lock before your if statement, and release it afterwards. If your deleting process is also looking for an exclusive lock, it will have to wait until the existing one is released before it'll run. `flock` is a very useful function for things like this.

Comment: @andrewsi This can be a practical solution. Is it common in caching systems? I am curious why there is no focus on this possible issue, and I missing something?

Comment: I've never used it explicitly in a caching system, but it works fine on a filesystem level. For a caching system, I'd timestamp the caches, and ignore ones that were too old - that way, your cleanup code could safely remove old files without worrying that they might still be being used.

Answer (score 0):

On failure, `file_get_contents` returns false, so what about this:

```
if (($output = file_get_contents($filename)) === false){
  // Do the processing.
  $output = 'Generated content';
  // Save cache file
  file_put_contents($filename, $output);
}
echo $output;
```

By the way, you may want to consider using `fpassthru`, which is more memory-efficient, especially for larger files. Using file_get_contents on large files (> 100 MB), will probably cause problems (depending on your configuration).

```
<?php
$fp = @fopen($filename, 'rb');
if ($fp === false){
  // Generate output
} else {
  fpassthru($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily `file_get_contents` return `FALSE` on error, so you could quick-bake it like:

```
if (FALSE !== ($buffer = file_get_contents())) {
    echo $buffer;
    return;
}
// PHP process
```

or similiar. It's a bit the quick and dirty way, considering you want to place the `@` operator to hide any warnings about non-existent files:

```
if (FALSE !== ($buffer = @file_get_contents())) {
```

The other alternative would be to lock, however that might prevent your cache-deletion to *not* delete the file if you have locked it.

Then left is to stall the cache your own. That means reading the file-creation time in PHP, check that it is < 5 minutes then for the file-deletion processing (5 minutes is exemplary) and then you would know that the file is already stale and for being replaced with fresh content. Re-create the file then. Otherwise read the file in, which probably is better then with `readfile` instead of `file_get_contents` and `echo`.